# Auto-wiring a List using util schema gives NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that i want to inject with a named list using Spring util namespace  `<util:list id="myList">` but Spring is looking for a collection of beans of type String instead. My broken test is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class ListInjectionTest {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("myList") private List<String> stringList;

    @Test public void testNotNull() {
        TestCase.assertNotNull("stringList not null", stringList);
    }
}
```

My context is:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

   <util:list id="myList">
       <value>foo</value>
       <value>bar</value>
   </util:list>

</beans>
```

But I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [collection of java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=myList)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:726)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
```

Which puzzles me rather as I figured this would be the way it was expected to work.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

This is due to a rather obscure part of @Autowired's behaviour, specified in [3.11.2. @Autowired](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation):

> It is also possible to provide all
>   beans of a particular type from the
>   `ApplicationContext` by adding the
>   annotation to a field or method that
>   expects an array of that type...
>
> The same applies for typed collections...

In other words, by saying `@Autowired @Qualifier("myList") List<String>`, you're actually asking for "give me the list of all beans of type `java.lang.String` that have the qualifier "myList".

The solution is mentioned in [3.11.3. Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

> If you intend to express
>   annotation-driven injection by name,
>   do not primarily use `@Autowired` - even
>   if is technically capable of referring
>   to a bean name through `@Qualifier`
>   values. Instead, prefer the JSR-250
>   `@Resource`  annotation which is
>   semantically defined to identify a
>   specific target component by its
>   unique name, with the declared type
>   being irrelevant for the matching
>   process.
>
> **As a specific consequence of this
>   semantic difference, beans which are
>   themselves defined as a collection or
>   map type cannot be injected via
>   `@Autowired` since type matching is not
>   properly applicable to them.** Use
>   `@Resource` for such beans, referring to
>   the specific collection/map bean by
>   unique name.

So use this in your test, and it works fine:

```
@Resource(name="myList") private List<String> stringList;
```

Comment: You are a life safer and so is stackoverflow.com! :)

Comment: I'd give this ten votes if I could.  You are Da Man, skaffman.

Comment: The fact that many have been confused by this means the semantics are really confusing. I wonder what was the reason behind such confusing design.

Comment: Wow, I consider Spring as one of my strongest areas in programming and I have never encountered this issue until today and you saved me tons of time. Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestion for how to get this to work with constructor/method injection, saying as @Resource does not support parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that could be happening is that you are autowiring a property of a bean. In such case you dont need to autowire it, but just create the setter method and use the property tag in the bean definition (when using xml) example:

```
<bean id="cleaningUpOldFilesTasklet" class="com.example.mypackage.batch.tasklets.CleanUpOldFilesTasklet">
    <property name="directoriesToClean">
        <list>
            <value>asfs</value>
            <value>fvdvd</value>
            <value>sdfsfcc</value>
            <value>eeerer</value>
            <value>rerrer</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the class:

```
public class CleanUpOldFilesTasklet extends TransferingFilesTasklet implements Tasklet{

private long pastMillisForExpiration;
private final String dateFormat = "MM.dd";
Date currentDate = null;

List<String> directoriesToClean;

public void setDirectoriesToClean(List<String> directories){
    List<String> dirs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String directory : directories){
        dirs.add(getSanitizedDir(directory));
    }
    this.directoriesToClean = dirs;
}
```

See, no `@Autowired` annotation in class.