# Autowire reference beans into list by type

Tags: java, spring

I have one class that has a list of objects of `Daemon` type.

```
class Xyz {    
    List<Daemon> daemons;
}
```

My spring configuration looks like this.

```
<bean id="xyz" class="package1.Xyz">
   <property name="daemons" ref="daemonsList">
</bean>

<bean id="daemon1" class="package1.DaemonImpl1"/>
<bean id="daemon2" class="package1.DaemonImpl2"/>

<bean id="daemonsList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="daemon1" />      
                <ref bean="daemon2" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Now instead of explicitly wiring each daemon implementation in list, is it possible to autowire all beans of type `Daemon` automatically in list. Problem I am trying to solve is, If someone creates a bean of new implementation of `Daemon` class and forgets to wire it into list.

I have seen this question somewhere on stackoverflow but not able to find that again. Apologies for it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363310/auto-wiring-a-list-using-util-schema-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception/1363435#1363435

Comment: Thanks skaffmen. I would try to understand the concept involved here.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It should work like this (remove the ArrayList bean from your XML):

```
public Class Xyz {    

    private List<Daemon> daemons;

    @Autowired
    public void setDaemons(List<Daemon> daemons){
        this.daemons = daemons;
    }

}
```

I don't think there's a way to do this in XML.

---

See:
[3.9.2. `@Autowired` and `@Inject`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation):

> It is also possible to provide all beans of a particular type from the
>   ApplicationContext by adding the annotation to a field or method that
>   expects an array of that type:

```
public class MovieRecommender {

  @Autowired
  private MovieCatalog[] movieCatalogs;

  // ...
}
```

> The same applies for typed collections:

```
public class MovieRecommender {

  private Set<MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs;

  @Autowired
  // or if you don't want a setter, annotate the field
  public void setMovieCatalogs(Set<MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs) {
      this.movieCatalogs = movieCatalogs;
  }

  // ...
}
```

BTW, as of Spring 4.x, [these lists can be ordered automatically using the `@Ordered` mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_core_container_improvements).

Comment: Thanks Sean. It worked. I thought, Adding `@Autowired` notation to `List<Daemons> daemons` would make spring search for beans which are of type `java.util.List`. It's amazing, how it finds out type of objects in list and wires them into list and finally wires list into main object.

Comment: @al. no prob. I use this feature a lot myself

Comment: When autowiring "List<Daemon> daemons", how does Spring know that it should look for beans of type Daemon, as this is generic type and will not be available at runtime?

Comment: @elyor that's not quite correct. Objects are subject to type erasure, fields and methods aren't. Reflection gives you the means through methods like [Method.getGenericParameterTypes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes--).

Answer (score 5):

Well, this can be achieved in two ways as stated in [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-autowire).

Below is the excerpt from the documentation.

> With byType or constructor autowiring mode, you can wire arrays and typed collections.

**1. autowire="byType"**

Autowiring using "byType" can be achieved if the type of the bean defined in the xml matches the type of list.

Example:

Motor.java

```
package com.chiranth;
public interface Motor 
{
   public void start();
}
```

ElectricMotor1.java

```
package com.chiranth;
public class ElectricMotor1 implements Motor
{
     public void start() 
     { 
         System.out.println("Motor 1 Started.");
     }
}
```

ElectricMotor2.java

```
package com.chiranth;
public class ElectricMotor2 implements Motor
{
    public void start() 
    {
        System.out.println("Motor 2 Started.");
    }
}
```

TeslaModelX.java

```
package com.chiranth;
import java.util.List;
public class TeslaModelX 
{
    private List<Motor> motor;

    public List<Motor> getMotor()
    {
        return motor;
    }

    public void setMotor(List<Motor> motor) 
    {
        this.motor = motor;
    }

    public void goForward()
    {
        for(Motor m :motor)
            m.start();
        System.out.println("Going Forward.");
    }
}
```

Spring.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="electricMotor1" class="com.chiranth.ElectricMotor1"/>
    <bean id="electricMotor2" class="com.chiranth.ElectricMotor2"/>

    <bean id="modelX" class="com.chiranth.TeslaModelX" autowire="byType"/>
</beans>
```

Test.java

```
package com.chiranth;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
        TeslaModelX modelx=(TeslaModelX)context.getBean("modelX");
        modelx.goForward();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Motor 1 Started.
Motor 2 Started.
Going Forward.
```

**2. autowire="constructor"**

Autowiring using "constructor" can be achieved if the type of the bean defined in the xml  matches the type of the argument in the constructor.

Example:

Considering the above Motor.java , ElectricMotor1.java and ElectricMotor2.java.

TeslaModelX.java

```
package com.chiranth;
import java.util.List;
public class TeslaModelX 
{
    private List<Motor> motor;

    public TeslaModelX(List<Motor> motor)
    {
        this.motor=motor;
    }

    public void goForward()
    {
        for(Motor m:motor)
            m.start();
        System.out.println("Going Forward.");
    }
}
```

Spring.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="electricMotor1" class="com.chiranth.ElectricMotor1"/>
    <bean id="electricMotor2" class="com.chiranth.ElectricMotor2"/>

    <bean id="modelX" class="com.chiranth.TeslaModelX" autowire="constructor"/>
</beans>
```

Test.java

```
package com.chiranth;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
        TeslaModelX modelX=(TeslaModelX)context.getBean("modelX");
        modelX.goForward();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Motor 1 Started.
Motor 2 Started.
Going Forward.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question for either solutions: would this work if "electricMotor1" and "electricMotor2" ... "electricMotorN" are defined not in the same spring.xml file but share the same ApplicationContext Container?