# How to initialize List inside Object using Spring Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How do I initialize List inside Object using Spring Annotation

```
@Component
class Accounts{
   private List<Transaction> _transaction;
   //getter setter
}
```

How do I initialize `List<Transaction> _transaction;` using Spring Annotation or else i
   have to define it in xml file.

But i dont want to write any xml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Spring Java `@Configuration` for such a task:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public List<Transaction> transactions() {
        ...... //Your logic to generate the list..
        return transactions;
    }
}
```

And in your Accounts class you have to use `@Resource`, not `@Autowired`, the semantics of injecting a list is a little different - if you use @Autowired, any bean of the same type will get injected into the list.

```
@Component
class Accounts{
   @Resource(name="transactions")
   private List<Transaction> _transaction;
   //getter setter
}
```

This is pure java solution and there is no xml involved in creating the list..

Answer (score 1):

If `Transaction` is a Bean with @Service, @Component or @Repository Annotation, you can just write @Autowired on top of your field.

```
@Component
class Accounts{

   @Autowired
   private List<Transaction> _transaction;
   //getter setter
}
```

Comment: But how do it come to know which is the implementing class Like ArrayList or some thing else..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446301/autowire-reference-beans-into-list-by-type . There is an example in the question on how you define the type of the list. [...] <bean id="daemonsList" class="java.util.ArrayList"> [...]