# Design approach when a class has many dependencies but requires to use only some of them based on some condition

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I have multiple classes which implement an interface and return an Object.

```
public interface DataFetcher {
    Data getData(Info info);
}

public class Data {
    private String name;
    private String value;
}


@Component
public class DataPointA implements DataFetcher {
    @Override
    public Data getData(Info info) {
        //..Do some processing
        return new Data("SomeName", valueComputed);
    }
}
```

Now I have about 20 data points which implement the DataFetcher class and returns the Data Object.

I autowire all the data points to a class and based on certain conditions I use certain data points.

```
@Component
public class DataComputer {
    @Autowired
    private DataPointA dataPointA;

    @Autowired
    private DataPointB dataPointB;
    .
    .
    .

    public void computeData(String inputType, Info info) {
        List<DataFetcher> dataFecthers;
        switch(inputType) {
            case "typeA" : dataFecthers  = ImmutableList.of(dataPointA, dataPointB);
                            break;

            .
            .
            .
            case "typeD" : dataFecthers  = ImmutableList.of(dataPointE, dataPointF, dataPointG);
                            break;
        }

        dataFetcher.forEach(dataPoint -> {
            //Do some processing with  dataPoint.getData(info)
        })
    }
}
```

As can be seen DataComputer class will have a whole list of dependencies which can become unmanageable. Also the data point to be used based on the inputType is known before hand so this can be extracted out. This was my attempt at doing it:

```
@Component 
public class DataComputationPointDecider {
    @Autowired
    private DataPointA dataPointA;

    @Autowired
    private DataPointB dataPointB;

    .
    .
    .

    @Bean
    public Map<String, List<DataFetcher>> getDataComputationPoints() {
        return new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, List<DataFetcher>>()
            .put("typeA", ImmutableList.of(dataPointA, dataPointB))
            .put("typeD", ImmutableList.of(dataPointE, dataPointF, dataPointG))
            .build();
    }
}
```

And then my DataComputer dependencies reduces:

```
@Component
public class DataComputer {
    @Autowired
    private Map<String, List<DataFetcher>> dataComputationPoints;

    public void computeData(String inputType, Info info) {
        List<DataFetcher> dataFecthers = dataComputationPoints.get(inputType);
        dataFetcher.forEach(dataPoint -> {
            //Do some processing with  dataPoint.getData(info)
        })
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to design this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything majorly wrong in your approach. But I'm suggesting one more option.

Instead of maintaining a map that maps an `inputType` with a list of `DataFetcher`, you can make a `DataFetcher` decide or say what input type(s) it can handle.

But this needs changing the interface of `DataFetcher` as

```
public interface DataFetcher {
    boolean canHandle(String inputType);
    Data getData(Info info);
}
```

The implementations would look like

```
@Component
public class DataPointA implements DataFetcher {
    @Override
    boolean canHandle(String inputType) {
         return "typeA".equals(inputType);
    }

    @Override
    public Data getData(Info info) {
        //..Do some processing
        return new Data("SomeName", valueComputed);
    }
}
```

Then you can just inject all `DataFetcher` as one single list (and need not add one `@Autowired` field for each one) and process it as

```
@Autowired
List<DataFetcher> dataFetchers;

...

dataFetchers.stream()
     .filter(dataFetcher -> dataFetcher.canHandle(inputType))
     .forEach(dataFetcher.getData(info));
```

**Advantages:**

In your current approach, if you add a new `DataFetcher` implementation, you need to add a `@AutoWired` field/member and modify the (getDataComputationPoints)map. But, with this, the inputTypes a `DataFetcher` can handle is specified with that itself and hence you just need to add new classes for new input types.

**Reference**

[Autowire reference beans into list by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446301/autowire-reference-beans-into-list-by-type)

**UPDATE:**

**Disadvantages**

1. The input types are specified inside the class means that you cannot easily find the list of `DataFetchers` (data points) for a given input type.
2. If you need to remove support for an inputType, then again you need to visit each implementation (to remove that inputType from `canHandle`). In your approach, it is about simply remove one map entry.

Comment: Interesting take on this. I like the advantage which you've pointed out. There is another way I've been thinking of passing the input types. Rather than having it in code saying which data points need to be used for a particular data point, I was thinking if this could be extended to a way where we have this data in a config file, which would require less java code change if the data points need to be swapped around. For ex in the file:
{ "typeA": ["DataPointA", "DataPointB"],
 "typeB": ["DataPointC", "DataPointE"]}

Comment: It has its pros and cons. Maintaining java class names in config (like `DataPointA`) is fragile. What if someone, later on, decides to rename it? Even in this case, you need to map the *string* `DataPointA` to `DataPointA` *object* which is not trivial (use reflection? any other way?)

Comment: True. Not necessary to map config file name with class name. That's just easier. One way is to have an enum which has strings matching the list of names in the config file and a mapper which returns the right implementation for each of the enum values. That way it is safe to change class name.

Comment: Then you anyway need to change that enum (which is java code) :) Then everytime, you add a new implementation, you need to 1) change config 2) add entry to enum and it is easy to forget one or both of these. Also you need to deal with typos in the config

Comment: Yeah true :) But would say that happening is rare and it would be nice to have at once glance what all data points are being used for a data point. In your approach the only disadvantage I see is that, the data points being used for a type can't be figured out quickly without looking at each class. And that would mean If I need to remove an implementation for a type I will need to go to individual classes to see that.

Comment: Fair enough. I have edited my answer to add the cons of this approach. But *to remove an implementation for a type* - you just have to go to *that implementation* and change the `canHandle`. It is difficult to remove a type altogether

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Factory pattern? This allows you to submit a request for an object instance based on certain criteria.

Comment: Hmm good point. In the factory pattern case, the factory will take care of return the `List<DataFetcher>` for a given input type instead of directly autowiring it. Would be an extension of what I have thought if I understood your intentions correctly