# Spring: Inject Any alternative

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The project I'm working on is a spring boot one and I need to migrate, from an EJB project, multiple implementations of the same interface.
There's a job that needs to use all of this instances and we would like to use a flexible implementations like the one supported in java ejbs:

```
@Inject
private @Any
Instance<FleetAnalyzerProvider> fleetAnalyzerProviders;
```

In the source project, it is used a provider builder:

```
    private void initializeProvider(String type) {
        try {
            final DeviceTypesProviderBuilder providerBuilder = new DeviceTypesProviderBuilder(type);
            final Instance qualifiedInstance = this.fleetAnalyzerProviders.select(providerBuilder);
            this.analyzerProvider = (FleetAnalyzerProvider) qualifiedInstance.get();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            this.logger.error("[initializeProvider] Failed for type [{}] due to: {}", type, e);
        }
    }
```

where DeviceTypesProviderBuilder is:

```
public class DeviceTypesProviderBuilder extends AnnotationLiteral<DeviceTypes> implements DeviceTypes {

    private final Type type;

    public DeviceTypesProviderBuilder(String type) {
        this.type = DeviceTypes.Type.getEnum(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Type value() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

And DeviceTypes:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD, TYPE})
public @interface DeviceTypes {

    Type value();

    enum Type {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a similar option in spring?

I saw a post ([Autowire reference beans into list by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446301/autowire-reference-beans-into-list-by-type)) with a syntax like this:

```
    @Autowired
    private FleetAnalyzerProvider[] fleetAnalyzerProviders;
```

But then how can I identify the correct provider?

The examples in the linked spring documentations are too simple and does not explicitly explain this particular possibility.

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct provider'?

Comment: The one corresponding the type I received in input. Each implementation of the provider interface has an annotation corresponding a specific value of the DeviceTypes, I need to find the corresponding one, just as the initializeProvider do in an ejb context.

Comment: It seems that in the end you are always casting to `FleetAnalyzerProvider` so what's the point?

Comment: I use the interface in the code, otherwise the problem to get the correct provider does not exists because I would have the  declarations of all the implementation.

Comment: do you mean `@Qualifier`? The annotation allows you to choose the autowiring implementation via `value` param

Comment: Yes, I don't know if it is correct, from the point of view of spring, to use a cycle on a list of FleetAnalyzerProvider to find the right one by the value in the qualifier

Comment: If you're looking for a particular bean, the `@Qualifier` is the choice. Once it's required to access all of them or filter it somehow, the collection autowiring would be most suitable there