# How can a class be instantiated without specifically assigning it to a variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning java and Springboot.  In an opensource repository https://github.com/gitbitex/gitbitex-new, The Bootstrap.java class conatains a code that is not being used. Specifically, Consider the following Code:

```
private final ModifiedObjectWriter modifiedObjectWriter;
private final EngineSnapshotTaker engineSnapshotTaker;
private final OrderBookSnapshotTaker orderBookSnapshotTaker;
private final List engineListeners;
   @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        startMatchingEngine(1);
        startOrderPersistenceThread(1);
        startTradePersistenceThread(1);
        startAccountPersistenceThread(1);
        startCandleMaker(1);
        startTickerThread(1);
    }
 private void startMatchingEngine(int nThreads) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
            String groupId = "MatchingEngine";
            KafkaConsumer<String, Command> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(getProperties(groupId),
                    new StringDeserializer(), new CommandDeserializer());
            MatchingEngineThread matchingEngineThread = new MatchingEngineThread(consumer, engineSnapshotStore,
                    engineListeners, appProperties);
            matchingEngineThread.setName(groupId + "-" + matchingEngineThread.getId());
            matchingEngineThread.start();
            threads.add(matchingEngineThread);
        }
    }
```

Now my observations about this. 
 (a) Top three classes, the modifiedObjectWriter, EngineSnapshotTaker, and OrderBookSnapshotTaker extends the EngineListener Class, but these classes are clearly not being used. 
(b) engineListener is being used but it appears to be an empty List. 
(c) The modifiedObjectWriter is annotated with @Component. 
(d)  At runtime, the engineListeners List is found to contain the instances of these Three Classes, 
 Now I wonder, How are these classes possibly injected in the engineListener List? Kindly refer to the repository for any details that I could have missed.

Comment: chatGPT told this: It's possible that these classes are being instantiated and added to the engineListeners list in other parts of the codebase.

Spring framework uses the Inversion of Control (IoC) pattern to manage the lifecycle and dependencies of objects in an application. One of the ways to achieve IoC in Spring is through the use of Dependency Injection (DI), where the framework injects dependencies into the objects that require them, rather than requiring the objects to create and manage their dependencies themselves.

Comment: and this: 
Based on the fact that the ModifiedObjectWriter is annotated with @Component, it's likely that Spring is responsible for instantiating it and injecting it into any other objects that require it. It's also possible that Spring is creating instances of the EngineSnapshotTaker and OrderBookSnapshotTaker classes as well, but they are not being used in this particular class and therefore are not injected into the engineListeners list.

It's worth checking the entire codebase for any other parts where these classes are being used and instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

**engineListeners contains instances of three classes because all three extend EngineListener class and thus bean belonging to each class is added to the list.**
That's probably because of a property of autowiring beans which follows that **when you autowire a list of particular class, then it will all beans belonging to that class or its subclasses are automatically added to that list.** For more information you can refer the following link: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446301/autowire-reference-beans-into-list-by-type`

Furtermore, you are using @RequiredArgsConstructor of Lombok, a constructor is automatically generated for you. **Since it's the only constructor, Spring uses it to autowire the dependencies of Bootstrap , including engineListeners (without the explicit need for an '@Autowired')**. Refer this for more details on automatic dependency injection without @Autowired -

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41092831/21497826
```

Comment: can't find any autowire annotation there. please check the codebase and the link.

Comment: Hi, since you are using @RequiredArgsConstructor, a constructor is automatically generated for you and since it's the only constructor, Spring uses it to **autowire** the dependencies (without the explicit need for an '@Autowired') as Bootstrap is a component. Refer this for more details - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41092831/21497826)

Answer (score 0):

There are two annotations on the Bootstrap class that are relevant here:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Bootstrap {
    // …
}
```

`@Component` is a Spring annotation. It means that it will be a Spring-managed "bean" and an instance of `Bootstrap` will be created by Spring and its dependencies will be injected into it. These dependencies will be resolved by looking at other Spring-managed beans and finding those that match the types required by the constructor.  Where the type being injected is a `List<T>`, Spring will use the type information and inject a list containing every bean that matches the required type. For example, `List<EngineListener>` will inject a list containing every `EngineListener` bean that's known to Spring.

`@RequiredArgsConstructor` is a Lombok annotation. During compilation, it causes a constructor to be generated with one argument for each final field in the class. The class has 18 final fields:

```
    private final OrderManager orderManager;
    private final AccountManager accountManager;
    private final OrderBookSnapshotStore orderBookSnapshotStore;
    private final TradeRepository tradeRepository;
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final ProductManager productManager;
    private final CandleRepository candleRepository;
    private final KafkaMessageProducer messageProducer;
    private final TickerManager tickerManager;
    private final AppProperties appProperties;
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
    private final RedissonClient redissonClient;
    private final List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    private final EngineSnapshotStore engineSnapshotStore;
    private final ModifiedObjectWriter modifiedObjectWriter;
    private final EngineSnapshotTaker engineSnapshotTaker;
    private final OrderBookSnapshotTaker orderBookSnapshotTaker;
    private final List<EngineListener> engineListeners;
```

This will result in Lombok generating a constructor with 18 arguments. Each of these arguments will be injected by Spring when it creates an instance of the `Bootstrap` class.

In my opinion, if you're learning Java, you may want to look at a different codebase. A class with 18 constructor arguments is very complex and some would argue that it needs to be split up into a number of smaller, more manageable classes. You may also want to avoid Lombok, at least until you understand what the code that it generates for you would have looked like.

Comment: Kindly continue explaining after "lombok will generate a constructor with 18 arguments and each them will be injected...", my question was how the classes get added to the engineListener List?

Comment: @RameshPareek I've added some information about how Lists are handled