# Inject Collection into @Bean method of @Configuration class (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, configuration

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**

Here is a Spring `@Configuration` class, and a test class for it.

There are 2 versions, depending on commented-out sections:

- One version injects a `Long` into the context, which Spring automatically converts to `List<Long>` as needed
- The other injects a `List<Long>` created by a method into the context. This version throws `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Long] found for dependency [collection of java.lang.Long]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}`

How do you inject a `List` or `Collection` into an `@Bean` method?

---

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    //@Bean
    //public Long theLong() {
        //return 42L;
    //}

    @Bean
    public List<Long> theList() { //Long theLong) {
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(42L);  // theLong);
        return list;
    }

    @Bean
    public Random random(
            List<Long> list) { // How to inject this?
            //Long theLong) {
        return new Random(list.get(0));
        //return new Random(theLong);
    }
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestConfig.class)
public class TestConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private Random random;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(-1170105035, random.nextInt());
    }
}
```

---

The reason is given in the accepted answer to [Auto-wiring a List using util schema gives NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363310/auto-wiring-a-list-using-util-schema-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception) **but that solution is not usable here** because `@Resource` cannot be used.

- Spring tries to create a `List<Long>` using any `Long` bean injected into the context, which it gathers up.
- The manually created `List<Long>` is ignored; Spring looks for single `Long` beans.
- `@Qualifier` doesn't seem to help
- `@Resource` cannot be used in method arguments.

---

**Note: This question is not a duplicate of any of:**

- [Inject a list of beans using Spring @Configuration annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892757/inject-a-list-of-beans-using-spring-configuration-annotation)
- [Spring: Injecting an Array or List of some type into a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508950/spring-injecting-an-array-or-list-of-some-type-into-a-bean)
- [Auto-wiring a List using util schema gives NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363310/auto-wiring-a-list-using-util-schema-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception)

Comment: Where are you getting the error in your code ?

Comment: @sotirios-delimanolis . Yup, the accepted answer to that question worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @reos  The exception is thrown when the Spring context boots, when you run the unit test

Comment: Ok, it has been answered in other question.