# How to read a file and assign it to an ArrayList in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-ioc

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Store {
    private final ArrayList<String> store;
    public ArrayList<String> getStore() {
        return store;
    }
    public Store(ArrayList<String> store){
        this.store = store;
    }
}
```

I have a text file called **`input.txt`**
I have a normal controller which is annotated with `@RestController` as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public class Controller {

    .
    .
    .

}
```

I need to do the following operations:

1. Read input.txt by using `Files.readAllLines(path,cs)` (from JDK 1.7)
2. Set the returned value(`List<String>`) to `Store.store`
3. I wanna use Spring annotations all the way (I'm writing a spring-boot application)
4. I need Store to be a Singleton bean.
5. The store needs to be initialized during the bootstrapping of my application.

This question might be too vague, but I have absolutely no idea about how to make it more specific.

**P.S.**
I'm a newbie to Spring.

Comment: I have a couple questions that should make your question more specific... 1) Are you trying to make a RESTful Web Service? If so, does this file need to be passed to a server, is it on the server, or is it on a user's local machine? 3) when you say arrayList<String> store, is this a list of store names? What format can you expect the input.txt to be in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363310/auto-wiring-a-list-using-util-schema-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception and https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-value-import-a-list-from-properties-file/

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make a RESTful WS.
and the input.txt is on the server, UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like using Constructor Injection would be ideal.

```
public class Store {
    private final List<String> storeList;

    @Autowired
    public Store(@Value("${store.file.path}") String storeFilePath) throws IOException {
            File file = new File(storeFilePath);
            storeList = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
    }
}
```

you will want to add the store.file.path property to your properties file that is read in by your spring context. You will also want to add a bean definition for Store

`<bean id="Store" class="com.test.Store" />`

Then your Rest Controller can look something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/store")
public class StoreRestController {

    @Autowired
    Store store;

    @RequestMapping(value="/get", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Store> getStore(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ResponseEntity<Store> response = new ResponseEntity<Store>(store, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }
}
```

There's a couple different ways to write your injection & controller so do some research and use the method that best suites your needs.

Comment: I would consider adding cache, since reading file is heavy operation, and should be made once

Comment: The file is readed just once per `Store` instance, so if default `singleton` scope is used for the bean, the file would be readed just once

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thanks